# Laravel Passport - get access token in controller by user id?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I was wondering if it was possible to get access_token by user's id. I'm using nodejs server to push notifications to client, and I need to validate connected user - curious if I could do that by using the same 'Bearer...' access token sent to user by oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution I'm feeding token from controller to node server, and after client connects to node server the client is requested to send bearer token - and extracting jti from it using jsonwebtoken package, which is used to compare with token received from controller.

Here goes the code:

**Controller**

```
$userTokenReceiver = $pm->receiver->tokens()->where('revoked', 'false')
    ->select('id')->get()->sortBy('created_at', true)->first();
if ($userTokenReceiver && $userTokenReceiver->toArray()['id'])
    $dataRedis->receiver_token = $userTokenReceiver->toArray()['id'];
```

**Node server**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
...
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.waitingAuthorize = true;
    // E> authentication_request: after connection asking client to provide token
    socket.emit('authentication_request');

    // O> authorize: waiting for client's response to auth request
    socket.on('authorize', function(token) {
        var decoded = jwt.decode(token);

        if ( !decoded || !decoded.jti ) {
            socket.disconnect(true);
            return;
        }

        socket.waitingAuthorize = false;
        socket.token = decoded.jti; // this is compared to token received from controller
    });
...
```